# Proving a system of equations has only one solution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to find all critic point of $f(x,y)=xe^y-ye^x$. So I calculated $\nabla f(x,y)=(e^y-ye^x, xe^y-e^x)$ and tried to solve $$\begin{cases}e^y-ye^x=0 \\ xe^y-e^x=0 \end{cases}\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \begin{cases}(1-xy)=0 \\ xe^y=e^x \end{cases}$$
A trivial solution is  {$x=1, y=1$}.
I'm pretty sure this is the sole solution, but I wasn't able to prove that!

---

My attempt:
$$\begin{cases}(1-xy)=0 \\ xe^y=e^x \end{cases}\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \begin{cases}y=\frac{1}{x} \\ y=x-\log{x} \end{cases}$$
I studied the difference $\left|x-\log{x} -\frac{1}{x}\right|$ and I suppose to find one and only one global minimum at $x=1$. $$D\left[\left|x-\log{x} -\frac{1}{x}\right|\right] \quad= \quad \operatorname{sgn}\left(x-\log{x} -\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2} \right)$$
The derivative has no stationary points, and $(\lim_{x\to0^+}=-\infty),$ $(\lim_{x\to+\infty}=+\infty)$; thus I must search among critical points. But here I got stuck, since the critical points lie where $\left(x-\log{x}-\frac{1}{x} \right)=0.$ So that's a circular definition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $g(x)=x - \ln x - \frac{1}{x}$. If we prove that it is strictly increasing for $x > 0$, then, it cannot have more than one zero. But its derivative, namely
$$ g'(x)= \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x} + 1 $$
is always $>0$ for $x > 0$, so we have concluded.

Comment: is it only a sufficient condition?

Comment: You could also, more generally, prove that it is strictly monotonic. If a function is strictly monotonic on some subset $A$, then it is bijective on such subset. This answers your question.